# Bash script loop only running once

Tags: bash, loops, bioinformatics

I am trying to parse an input file (my test file is 4 lines) and then query an online biological database. However my loop seems to stop after returning the first result.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
        echo "No input file to parse given. Give me a BLAST output file"
else
        file=$1
        #Extracts GI from each result and stores it on temp file.
        rm -rf /home/chris/TEMP/tempfile.txt
        awk -F '|' '{printf("%s\n",$2);}' "$file" >> /home/chris/TEMP/tempfile.txt
        #gets the species from each gi.
        input="/home/chris/TEMP/tempfile.txt"
        while read -r i
        do
                echo GI:"$i"
                /home/chris/EntrezDirect/edirect/esearch -db protein -query "$i" | /home/chris/EntrezDirect/edirect/efetch -format gpc | /home/chris/EntrezDirect/edirect/xtract -insd source o
rganism | cut -f2 
        done < "$input"
        rm -rf /home/chris/TEMP/tempfile.txt
fi
```

For example, my only output is

```
GI:751637161

Pseudomonas stutzeri group
```

whereas I should have 4 results. Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

This is the format of the sample input:

```
TARA042SRF022_1 gi|751637161|ref|WP_041104882.1|    40.4    151 82  2   999 547 1   143 2.8e-21 110.9
TARA042SRF022_2 gi|1057355277|ref|WP_068715547.1|   62.7    263 96  1   915 133 80  342 7.1e-96 358.6
TARA042SRF022_3 gi|950462516|ref|WP_057369049.1|    38.3    47  29  0   184 44  152 198 5.1e+01 36.2
TARA042SRF022_4 gi|918428433|ref|WP_052479609.1|    37.5    48  29  1   525 668 192 238 6.1e+01 37.0
```

Comment: You might try redirecting the standard input of `esearch` from `/dev/null`; it appears to be reading the rest of the input file before `read -r i` runs again. `esearch -db protein -query "$i" < /dev/null | ...`.

Comment: You could simplify your awk like so: `awk -F '|' '{print $2}'`.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, that's seems to be the only option (apart from that the script can theoretically be run as something like `bash -e -o pipefail script.sh`).

Comment: @chepner Adding the `< /dev/null` worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Note that some bioinformatics libraries like Biopython offer some convenient interface for parsing Blast results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that `read -r i` is returning with a non-zero exit status on its second call, indicating that there is no more data to be read from the input file. This usually means that a command inside the `while` loop  is *also* reading from standard input, and is consuming the remainder of the file before `read` has a chance.

The only candidate here is `esearch`, as `echo` does not read from standard input and the other commands are all reading from the previous command in the pipeline. Redirect standard input for `esearch` so that it does not consume your input data inadvertently.

```
while read -r i
do
    echo GI:"$i"
    /home/chris/EntrezDirect/edirect/esearch -db protein -query "$i" < /dev/null |
      /home/chris/EntrezDirect/edirect/efetch -format gpc |
      /home/chris/EntrezDirect/edirect/xtract -insd source organism |
      cut -f2 
done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` to extract columns from an ASCII file, use the `-d` option to denote the delimiter and `-f` to specify the column. Wrap everything in a loop like so

```
$ cat data.txt
TARA042SRF022_1 gi|751637161|ref|WP_041104882.1|    40.4    151 82  2   999 547 1   143 2.8e-21 110.9
TARA042SRF022_2 gi|1057355277|ref|WP_068715547.1|   62.7    263 96  1   915 133 80  342 7.1e-96 358.6
TARA042SRF022_3 gi|950462516|ref|WP_057369049.1|    38.3    47  29  0   184 44  152 198 5.1e+01 36.2
TARA042SRF022_4 gi|918428433|ref|WP_052479609.1|    37.5    48  29  1   525 668 192 238 6.1e+01 37.0

$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

for gi in $(cut -d"|" -f 2 data.txt); do
    echo $gi
done

$ bash t.sh
751637161
1057355277
950462516
918428433
```

Edit:
I cannot reproduce the problem but I feel it is linked to newlines and/or the usage of a temp file. My suggestions omits this but does not answer your actual question (but your problem I guess)

Comment: It just switches to a for loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I have no problem parsing the gi from each line, this is done with the awk command and stored to a temp file, the problem is in the while loop afterwards.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem but I feel it is linked to newlines and/or the usage of a temp file. My suggestions omits this.

Comment: @Rolf I used your cut command to get rid of the intermediate file, thanks for that.